VS Code working with csv file, command 'edit-csv.edit' not found
I been working with CSV file in vscode and using extensions like Edit csv to edit csv files with an Excel-like table ui but now whenever I click on edit csv button at the top right I get this message "command 'edit-csv.edit' not found", another extension is Rainbow csv to highlights columns, has also stopped working too.
Has anyone ever encountered this problem, what can I do to solve it?
It used to not work if I didn't trust the folder but even with a trusted folder It still did not work.
Reinstall the extension, disable or enable doesn't help either.
I try to reinstall vscode thinking I might have messed with something and it doesn't solve the problem!
enter image description here
